# How to calculate a lot of records in DB with reasonable time

Tags: database, recommendation-engine, bigdata

If I have a vector (for example: `(5,4,6,8)` ) in my application and I want to find similarity to other vector in my DB, let say for simplicity that I'm calculating distance between two vectors with [Manhattan distance](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Manhattan_distance).

What I need is a way to calculate the algorithm (Manhattan distance in my example) between my vector and all the vectors that are stored in my DB, Can I do 10 million vectors under a couple of seconds ?

Comment: 100,000 is not big data, Manhattan distance is simple to compute - I think any SQL engine can do it quickly.

Comment: Thanks @Arvo I've checked it and you right..
but the question still stands, I've update the questions with a greater number

Comment: Stupid question I know, but why you need that? To find shortest distance? To cluster vectors somehow? Some other comparison? How often you expect to run this procedure? Is your vector arbitrary?

Comment: I'm trying to find similarity between 2 users (that are represented by their vector).
I'm developing a system that will find a Match between people that search for roommate (based on their preferences)

Comment: This is pretty general then, I have got no clever ideas, sorry :( Likely Bartłomiej Twardowski's answer points to possible direction. I would try some clustering algorithms first - you can precompute (about sqrt(records count)) clusters, containing reference vectors and their neighbourhood points; so it is not hard to add any new point to precomputed clusters. To find match(es) you need to find nearest reference vectors from clusters and then search in these clusters only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You really deal with a lot of data, what You really need is an Approximate Near Neighborhood  -  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search#Approximate_nearest_neighbor implementation. Take look at Annoy - https://pypi.python.org/pypi/annoy/1.8.0 project page. There is a benchmark with other ANN projects wich You can find interesting. Maybe there is a implementation as a plugin for DB, but I am not aware of such. However,  ANN can be also used to pre-compute top-n NN and store them in DB as a list for User/Item.